# Creating a Folder in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a basic JS script in NodeJs. The script will create a folder with the name of the folder to be reponses_timestamp.

I have written the attached script, however, when it runs, i receive an error which says:

> `Einval: invalid argument.`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Test.js**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const today = new Date();
const date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
const time = today.getHours()+":"+today.getMinutes()+":"+today.getSeconds();
const dateTime = date + '_' + time;
const uniqueIdentifier = dateTime;
// const folderName = './responses' + '_' + uniqueIdentifier;

try {
    if (!fs.existsSync('./responses' + '_' + uniqueIdentifier)) {
    fs.mkdirSync('./responses' + '_' + uniqueIdentifier)
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

[image]

Comment: did either answer help you with your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Probably - the problem is with the folder name. In Windows folder should not have special characters, like `:`

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67521175/1952287) the issue is due to the usage of the colon `:` because Windows (also per your screenshot Windows shown as the path) will not allow special characters.

It wasn't mentioned a solution so I wanted to mention for what you're doing this can be achieved easily with [`moment js`](https://momentjs.com/) using two lines of code and a substitution of the colon for a dash:

```js
const date = new Date()
const uniqueIdentifier = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM')

console.log('uuid', uniqueIdentifier)

// Result: "uuid" "2021-05-13-11-05"
```

and even a one-liner:

```js
const uniqueIdentifier = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM')

console.log('uuid', uniqueIdentifier)

// Result: "uuid" "2021-05-13-11-05"
```